# Windows: Password protect all user interaction on a laptop dedicated for public presentation

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome

I have a laptop which i have dedicated to present a web-page in chrome browser on to a TV. This TV and laptop would be in a public place inside my office. I would want any interaction through mouse/keyboard/track-pad be restricted. i.e. whenever a user tries to interact with the laptop it should pop-up a password dialog box and only allow interaction after authorizing with the password.

I think I have see something similar being done when I visited a conference long time back. But, I don't find much help or leads on how this can be achieved in google.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier, just to lock the machine, and require individual user accounts to the machine?

Comment: it is a machine used to present a predefined web-page in chrome browser to the TV. Its not for  other people to login.

Comment: The password prompt you want doesn't exist, you will have to come up with your own solution.

Comment: Why would the laptop be in a public place?  Why not just put it somewhere generally secure, like in a desk drawer, with just the monitor cord exposed?  Every time I have working on public facing screens like this, we have physically secured the machine for fear of people using it, or stealing it.